# Como fazer com que um form envie e-mail para 2 destinatários?

Tags: php

Criei um formulário onde o usuário preenche com algumas informações e é enviado um e-mail pra mim com essas informações. Só que no momento ele está enviando apenas para 1 e-mail.

Abaixo segue o código:

```
  <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header ("location: sucesso.html");
$radio=$_POST[radio];
$nome=$_POST[nome];
$num=$_POST[num];
$mes=$_POST[mes];
$aviso=$_POST[aviso];
$email=$_POST[email];
$assunto=$_POST[assunto];
$mensagem=$_POST[mensagem];

mail("meu@email.com","Chegou um e-mail","
Campo 1: $radio
Campo 2: $num
Campo 3: $nome
Campo 4: $mes
Campo 7: $aviso 
");

echo "sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!";

?>
```

> #### Como fazer para que ele também envie os e-mails para um outro destinatário, só que (oculto)?

No caso ele deve enviar os e-mails para um e-mail comum, e outro pra um oculto.

Comment: Se não for um envio em massa, prefira usar o `mail()` duas vezes em separado, pois nem todos os mailers respeitam a cópia oculta. Em alguns casos, há o "vazamento" de headers, e isso pode revelar um receptor no `bcc`.

Answer (score 1):

O email oculto você informa no *header* da mensagem, exemplo:

```
// Vários 'para' separados por vírgula
$para  = 'pessoa1@exemplo.com' . ', ';
$para .= 'pessoa2@exemplo.com';

// Assunto
$assunto= 'Assunto';

// Mensagem
$mensagem = "Alguma mensagem";

// Headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Headers Adicionais
$headers .= 'To: Alguem <alguem@exemplo.com>, Fulano <fulano@exemplo.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Mim <mim@exemplo.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: outro@exemplo.com' . "\r\n"; // Com cópia
$headers .= 'Bcc: pessoaoculta@exemplo.com' . "\r\n"; // Cópia oculta

// Enviar
mail($para, $assunto, $menssagem, $headers);
```

Mais informações: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php

Comment: Seria legal incluir a variável $para no header também, para o email não ser considerado um spam